# R ggraph: how to plot bi-directional arrows in network?

Tags: r, ggraph, tidygraph

I would like to do a network graph in R using `ggraph` where an an edge relationship goes both ways `A -> B` and `B -> A`. I would like top plot this with `ggraph` as a single bi-directional arrow? A solution on [ggraph's Github issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/240) is to use `arrow(ends="both")`, but this will plot two bi-directional arrows, while I want a single bi-directional arrow?

Is this possible with `ggraph`? Or maybe I should specify my underlying graph differently?

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
df <- data.frame(form=c(2,1,3), to = c(1,2,1)) |> 
                       as_tbl_graph() 

df |> 
  ggraph(layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(ends="last"),
                 end_cap = circle(8, 'mm'),
                 start_cap = circle(3, 'mm'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the cap `circle()`-size to the same value for start and end it will appear like one edge with arrows on both sides. Alternatively you can use `igraph::plot()`.

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

df <- data.frame(form=c(2,1,3), to = c(1,2,1)) |> 
  as_tbl_graph() 

df |> 
  ggraph(layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(ends="last"),
                 end_cap = circle(8, 'mm'),
                 start_cap = circle(8, 'mm'))
```

[image]

```r
plot(df)
```

[image]